# Delete table in all the rendering pages of a single page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, classname

I am having a table like:

```
<table id="toc" class="toc" border="1" summary="Contents">
</table>
```

in many pages. All these pages are rendered in a single page. When I apply the javascript to delete that using on load with the below:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('toc');
if(tbl) tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
```

Only one table is deleted and not the others. I am trying to delete the tables in all the rendering pages using javascript. How to do this?

Edit :
I myself found the solution

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onLoad = load(); 
  function load(){var tbl = document.getElementById('toc'); 
   if(tbl) tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);} 
 </script>
```

Comment: you're asking the same question over and over again. Even the code you're posting is not your own. Please stop it.

Comment: hm, do we have now automatic comments? interesting.

Comment: hey SileNTGHost in the previous post i have asked deleting a table (single page).. here i am asking for deleting table rendered from diff pages.

Comment: @Aruna: I've reported you for drive-by downvoting

Comment: And the code i have used is the answer posted by safraz and it works only for the single table..

Answer (score 2):

An `ID` is a **unique** identifier, which basically means: *There can be only one.*

Try looking up by tagname (`table`) instead and comparing the classname.

```
var allTables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {
    // Array.indexOf may not be available, see
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

    if (allTables[i].className.split(' ').indexOf('toc') != -1) {
        var node = allTables[i];
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am having a  single page which contains pages rendered from different pages. And in each of its Onload i have given the script to delete the table but still its reflected in only one page.. And not in all the pages rendered to the main page..

Comment: I can't quite understand what you mean. Can you give a url to the page in question, or an identical test case?